# Pass Variable To Simple Modal Popup From URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Have a table created from a sql query am trying to pass the variable pmntid via the following code:

```
?>
<td class="listingTextLeft">
<a href="?pmntid=<?php echo $row[0] ?>" class="pmntDetail"><?php echo $row[20] ?></a>
</td>
<?php
```

The link shows the correct pmntid however I am unable to pass it through the following jquery:

```
    <script>
    jQuery('.pmntDetail').each(function(i,v){
        jQuery(v).click(function(paymentID){
         paymentID.preventDefault();
         paymentID.stopPropagation();
         var pmntid = <?php echo $row[0]; ?>
         console.log("ID: ", pmntid);
         $("#pmntDetailPopup").modal({position: ["5%"]});
      });

 });
    </script>
```

The console log shows pmntid as undefined. I need this pmntid passed to a simple modal popup which displays in the pmntDetailPopup div on the same page where I run a sql query to populate fields with results from the query.

The popup works fine and all fields are populated if I use a constant in the query so the error is definitely in passing the pmntid.

Comment: `paymentID` is a bad variable name for event.

Comment: I think a semicolon sign is missing in your code after line `var pmntid = <?php echo $row[0]; ?>` , where you initialize the `pmntid` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a data attribute:

```
<a href="?pmntid=<?php echo $row[0] ?>" data-rid="<?php echo $row[0] ?>" class="pmntDetail"><?php echo $row[20] ?></a>
```

and read it in the click event

```
var pmntid = $(this).data("rid");
console.log("ID: ", pmntid);
```

Comment: Awesome, thankyou very much @epascarello, that works and I get the correct value in the console. Just one quick further question - to use this for my query I would put `$pmntid = $_GET['pmntid'];` in my pmntDetailPopup div?